# What is the electron to muon ratio in 2 lepton events?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

I've obtained a value of 0.857 from collider data but the skew is confusing. I do not understand why there would be a favor in the direction of electrons.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome Is_Show! You are more likely to get a response if your question doesn't force people to guess or reverse engineer what you are asking. What is the source of "0.857" number? (e.g. Give a link if possible.) What kind of interactions? Which collider? (I might guess the LHC, but there have been a lot more.)

Answer (score 1):

You do not give a link for the number you quote, but in general one would expect an asymmetry.

Muons are heavier, which means that part of the general energy phase space is not available from energy momentum conservation. For example for a photon to go into a muon pair its energy necessarily should be twice the muon mass.

If you read [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/14/11/2401) where they are studying charged particle distributions , you will see that the low transverse momentum particles are much more than the high. This will be true for all particles created at the LHC, which means that, for example, low energy photons will be much more probable than the high energy needed for muon pair production. This logic should hold for all types of reaction in the LHC scatterings.